# What is the purpose of the `contracts_runtime.scale` file in the `cargo-contracts` repository?

Tags: metadata, scale-codec, cargo-contract, accountid

[Cargo Contract](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/) is a popular tool for developing ink! contracts.

This tool is known to work well with the [substrate contracts node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node), and I thought it should work with other chains that support pallet contracts as well.

I'm currently trying to adapt cargo contract to work with Substrate chains that use the `AccountId20` type and `EthereumSignature`s instead of the more "normal" `AccoutId32` type.

My question is, what is the content and purpose of the [contracts_runtime.scale file](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/blob/master/crates/cargo-contract/src/cmd/runtime_api/contracts_runtime.scale)? If I had to guess I would guess that it is scale encoded metadata from the substrate contracts node. But is that right? And if so, do I need to supply my own encoded metadata to make cargo contract work with my chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metadata was downloaded from a running `substrate-contracts-node` and is used to generate the APIs and types required for constructing contract extrinsics and querying storage from a compatible node.

Therefore, at the moment `cargo-contract` will only work against nodes which are compatible with these types. Supporting nodes using different types and configurations will indeed require downloading and storing the metadata for each different target node.

So for compatibility with multiple node configurations will require making the codebase generic over the environment types e.g. `AccountId` and `Balance`, and additionally supporting the metadata for multiple nodes.

It is a hugely important goal for us to support this functionality for any type of chain which uses `pallet-contracts`.

Related issue: https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/issues/1168

Answer (score 0):

I found some helpful context in the docs for the `subxt` macro https://docs.rs/subxt/0.29.0/subxt/attr.subxt.html

I guess this macro generates a strongly typed API from the metadata. So I guess in the case of changing the AccountId type, I would need to re-generate the metadata.

I still don't know the exact binary format, but that doesn't matter so much to me.